# Airflow - Grab and sanitize run_id for DockerOperator

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I'm using Airflow to run Python workflows in Docker.  DockerOperator launches a container and attaches a temporary volume.  This volume needs to persist between multiple tasks so that they're able to store and share files throughout the DAG.  A final cleanup task then removes that volume.

I'd like to give the container (as well as the volume) a name which is unique to the DAG run; using a UUID or, preferably, the run_id.  That way, the same DAG can be run multiple times simultaneously and each set of containers/volumes would be unique to the run and not conflict with one another.

The problem I have is that generating a UUID in the DAG would create a unique UUID *per task*, due to the way that DAG scripts behave in Airflow.  The DAG run_id is also problematic because it contains characters that aren't allowed for container names and needs to be sanitized first.

In the following example, `some_unique-id` will have a unique ID *per task*, not per run.  The `run_id` of the DAG run can be referenced as a template container name, but it needs to be sanitized, and I don't think the template even gets parsed in the volume name.

Is there some way to go about this?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator

dag_name = 'TestDAG'

with DAG(dag_name) as dag:

  ######################################################################
  # How do I get a sanitized run_id or some run-specific UUID??
  some_unique_id = ''
  ######################################################################

  temp_volume_name = f'temp_airflow_{dag_name}_{some_unique_id}'

  cleanup = DockerOperator(
    container_name = f'airflow_task_{dag_name}_cleanup_{some_unique_id}',
    command =  f'docker volume rm {temp_volume_name}',
    task_id = f'cleanup',
    image = f'cleanupimage:latest',
    volumes = [ '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' ],
    auto_remove = True,
  )

  def py_docker_operator(task_id: str, script: str):
    return DockerOperator(
      container_name = f'airflow_task_{dag_name}_{task_id}_{some_unique_id}',
      command = f'python /code/{script}',
      task_id = task_id,
      image = f'mypythonimage:latest',
      volumes = [ f'{temp_volume_name}:/tmp/{dag_name}' ],
      working_dir = f'/tmp/{dag_name}',
      auto_remove = True
    )

  task1 = py_docker_operator('task1', 'script1.py')
  task2 = py_docker_operator('task2', 'script2.py')

  task1 >> task2 >> cleanup
```

Comment: Tasks can potentially run on separate workers. How would the volume be accessed in the case the tasks run on different workers?

Comment: Good point.  In this case, it's all running on a single instance node.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Jinja's hashing filters](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-filters) to create a deterministic hash of a value unique to the execution that all tasks can reference?

Comment: this gives me OriginalError: no filter named 'hash'

Comment: also doing this manually the hash seems to always be computed at dag load time not task runtime. if anyone has code for this i need a hash of the run_id for another purpose. thank!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem that I cannot use `{{run_id}}` as a unique identifier as it contains characters such as ':'. I wanted hash the `{{run_id}}` to make a unique identifier that is safe to use in many contexts. This turned out to be a lot harder than it appears. The challenge is that the dag is evaluated upon loading it and so if I call any hashing functions in the construction of the dag it is memorized. For example if I do this in a airflow script:

```py
# hash the run_id as contains colons which are deemed illegal by Java on Windows
def hasher(my_value):
    sha_1 = hashlib.sha1()
    sha_1.update(str(my_value).encode('utf-8'))
    return sha_1.hexdigest()

airflow_details = {"run_id": "{{run_id}}", "run_id_hashed": hasher("{{run_id}}")}
```

then at dag load time it will run the `hasher("{{run_id}}")` and that value will be used by every task in every instance that uses `airflow_details`. The value of "{{run_id}}" at dag load time it might be nothing, or empty, or null. This means that every time the dag runs all tasks that use `run_id_hashed` get the same value.

Another answer gives a good hint which is to use a jinja2 filter such as:

```
{"run_id_hashed": "{{run_id | hash }}"}
```

yet the built in hash functions of jinja2 are not enabled by default in Airflow 2.0.2.

The fix is to create a `user_defined_filters` entry on our DAG that will do the hashing. First define your hasher function:

```py
import hashlib

def hasher(my_value):
    sha_1 = hashlib.sha1()
    sha_1.update(str(my_value).encode('utf-8'))
    return sha_1.hexdigest()
```

Then we have to define `user_defined_filters` on the dag that has a lambda that will call our hashing function:

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id="whatever",
    user_defined_filters=dict(hash=lambda my_value: hasher(my_value))
    ) as dag:
```

now we can apply that filter within any task:

```py
big_query_task= bigquery.BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
    task_id='blah',
    sql=my_sql.format(**merge_dicts(main_config, {"run_id_hashed": "{{run_id | hash }}"})),
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    dag=dag
)
```

In that we are creating a task using an operator and we have applied the custom user defined filter `hash` to the `run_id`. The dag will evaluate `"{{run_id | hash }}"` for every instance of the task by running our lambda that will call our `hasher` function.